# In python, how to use np array to manipulate multi-dimension efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy

I have tens of thousands of 32 X 32 RGB images in the data set. eg.

X_train, shape (123123, 32, 32, 3)

I'd like to gray out the rgb, and change the shape to (123123, 32, 32, 1)

I have code here which is extremely insufficient, I am wondering what's the best way to do it. I am on AWS G2 or P2 host, so I have GPU.

Thanks.

```
def grayedOut(x) :
    out = []

    for n in range(len(x)) :
        nv = []
        for i in range(len(x[n])) :
            iv = []
            for j in range(len(x[n,i])) :
                r,g,b = x[n,i,j,0], x[n,i,j,1], x[n, i,j,2]
                gray = np.uint8(0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b)

                iv.append(np.asarray([gray]))
            nv.append(iv)
        out.append(nv)
    return np.asarray(out)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply write

```
def grayedOut(x):
    return x.dot([0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])[..., np.newaxis].astype(np.uint8)
```

- `x.dot([0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])`: Compute the gray component for each pixel. The resulting shape will be `(123123, 32, 32)`
- `[..., np.newaxis]`: Creates a new axis to the result, giving the required shape `(123123, 32, 32, 1)`
- `.astype(np.uint8)`: Convert the data type to uint8.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `images` is your array of *all* RGB images. Then the following code produces the array of grayscale images:

```
coeffs = np.array([0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])
gray = np.apply_along_axis(coeffs.dot, 3, images).astype(np.uint8)
```

I hope this code is faster than your triple loop.

Comment: This is better than mine, but seems not as fast as the one from Kenytm. Thanks anyway